# Graphics DrawImage - ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have timer which adds new image on the panel every second. First i create my global variable Graphics g, create timer in the construcor and start timer there. In my Panel method i create Graphics object (g = e.Graphics) and then in my timer method i use that g object to draw new image. Can't find what's the problem, here's the core code (program stops when on the first call - g.DrawImage()):

```
public partial class MyClass: Form
{
private Timer addImage;

private Image img;

private Graphics g;
private Point pos;

public MyClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    img = Image.FromFile("C:/image.png");
    pos = new Point(100, 100);

    addImage = new Timer()
    {
        Enabled = true,
        Interval = 3000,
    };
    addImage.Tick += new EventHandler(AddImage);
    addImage.Start();
}

private void MyPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    g = e.Graphics;
}

private void AddImage(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    g.DrawImage(img, pos); // ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'

    MyPanel.Invalidate();
}
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint where the code blows up and verify that your inputs are what you are expecting them to be.  Also, put a try/catch around the code in AddImage so you can inspect the exception and see what's really going on.  I am assuming you are using a version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Files should never be placed in the root directory.

Comment: Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter.. - Also: location and speeing of your path are suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to draw your image in the `OnPaint` override because the `Graphics` object will be disposed. To redraw the form you can call `Refresh`. Also look that your that your path to the image is correct.

```
public partial class MyClass : Form
{
    private readonly Image _image;
    private readonly Point _position;
    private bool _isImageVisible;

    public MyClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\img.png");
        _position = new Point(100, 100);

        var addImageCountdown = new Timer
        {
            Enabled = true,
            Interval = 3000,
        };
        addImageCountdown.Tick += new EventHandler(AddImage);
        addImageCountdown.Start();
    }

    private void AddImage(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        _isImageVisible = true;
        Refresh();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_isImageVisible)
        { 
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, _position);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```